# Magmi import from remote using column mapper

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

i'm a magmi beginner user , i'm french and my english is not so good 
i want to import my csv using magmi and i don't want to changes names column ( after i want to set a daily remote import with my ftp )

my csv have 4 collumns of categories separeted by dash as you can see ( categories collumn is specified by , categories niveau 1 ... categories niveau 2 etc ) in just one collumn of categories it can have several categories

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425293304-csv-test.jpg

---categories niveau 1

------categories niveau 2

----------categories niveau 3

--------------categories niveau 4

this is what i want

in magmi i use the column mapper but i don't know what name to specify in columns mapper list or new name col , i have tried all the things , and all have failed , if anyone can help me for resolving this

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both column mapper (to rename columns to "processable" names) and value replacer (to combine remapped column values to a usable category tree definition)

in column mapper : enter all column names comma separated, and then a new (no space, lowercase) processable name (Référeces CDiscount (SKU) Code EAN => sku)

For categories columns : Catégorie niveau 1 => catlevel1 etc...

Once done, use the value replacer plugin, and in attribute to replace enter: categories

in new value for categories enter : {item.catelevel1}/{item.catlevel2}/{item.catlevel3}/{item.catlevel4}

Or, another ,maybe better option would be to create a preprocessing script that would transform the header line from "French human oriented columns" into "processable" column names.

Comment: hi @dweeves , first i would like to thank you for your quick response, 
this is what i made 
[link](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-10-1425477678-magmi2.jpg)
I think it matches to what you propose to me
bracket () are not supported in column list , when i try to insert one ( for References cidsocunt (sku) for example ) it made me an error 
for eancode or other names none magento interegated terminology , an attribut was created 
so , this is what i made and i had 6 errors "sku no found"
csv separotor check
create new items placed

for preprocessing i dont know how to make it 

thank you a lot